# Excel 2019 lookup issue

Tags: excel-formula

I have a data table, I need to document the row number, column number and value. However, I have the value and row number but need a formula to get the column number.

I have attempted to use Lookup and match, with no success.

Comment: Please give us some data to work with, such as a table of sample data and what you are looking to do. Otherwise the answers will only be generic. Such as `COLUMN()`.

Comment: Generic is fine

Comment: Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) which will help you edit your question utilizing markdown format. Or even an image of your data and the results you expect would go a long way!

Comment: I would advise for you to check out the following functions available in Excel for obtaining cell references. [Column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/column-function-44e8c754-711c-4df3-9da4-47a55042554b), [Row](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/row-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d), [Address](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/address-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89).

Comment: @AlecB. Actually *generic usually isn't fine.*  Your question lacks any of the context we need to actually help you.  It *absolutely* matters what Excel formula you used to find the  value in the data table, and how you found the row.  Lacking those two formulas, or some sample data, it's almost impossible to help.  If I said "I am having trouble finding a value in my spreadsheet" there's virtually nothing you can do to help me unless I provide the context of sample data, my existing formulas, or both.  We want to help but have no place to start.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Think coordinates. If I know my value is in row 20, and the value is 739, I am looking for the corresponding column.
It's the reverse of index.